# UICollectionView Not Loading Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

Here is the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` code I have:

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //do stuff, set label text

if (indexPath.section == 0) cell.label.text = [words1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else if (indexPath.section == 1) cell.label.text = [words2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else if (indexPath.section == 2) cell.label.text = [words3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
```

I register the cell type in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

I have my collection view setup in my storyboard with delegates and datasource linked up as normal.

Now my issue... I have two approaches, both with problems. I have 3 sections, each drawing from a unique array of data.

1. After I have fetched the required data, I use `[_collectionView reloadData]`. This loads the correct number of cells, as per the array count, but the cells offscreen are not populated. So when I scroll them onscreen, they have not has their label set.
2. Instead of the above, I try reloading each section as the data is fetched (a preferred route) using the following code (once per section):

   `[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
       [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
   } completion:nil];`

However, the problem using this method, is that after it has reloaded, it fills my collection view with the correct number of cells, but the cells themselves are blank, no text set on the labels.

In both scenarios, if I scroll the non-loading cells onscreen, offscreen and back on again, they will load. But the first time you see them, they don't.

Comment: This code says to only set the label on the first 3 cells of a given section so your problem is in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You probably meant indexPath.section ==0 { cell.label.text = @"text" }

Comment: 1. else if (indexPath.row == 2) cell.label.text = @"text here";. So row 4 doesn't has label.

Comment: Try creating an array with NSString for all the cells you have. As you see, cell for 4 row will not display any text. And this code will work for all your sections (you don't check the section for cell)

Comment: Whoops! I was a big dumb dumb and typed wrongly. Brain now in gear, see my corrected code. I have been setting text from arrays as per section. Sorry about that.

Comment: can you upload your project to github?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Placing your UI code, such as creating `UILabel` (not nil) inside the `layoutSubviews` method is bad.

Moving this code to the `init` method on my custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, fixed my problem if cell UI not consistently.